# Good reference for studying measure zero sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

We have Riemann integration in our next semester, for which I need to cover basic ideas of measure or length of a set in $\mathbb R$. Can anyone tell me how much do I need to know about measure theory or what parts are sufficient to cover to understand the Riemann integration?

Also can anyone suggest me some reference materials to cover up those essential topics of measure theory?

(Note that I must cover only those things which are essential and in a very short time - say one week. I am not going to study the entire measure theory and secondly I know almost nothing of measure theory).

Comment: I learned my measure theory from the book "Measure Theory" by Donald Cohn, that I found quite well done and easy to follow, with good exercises.

Comment: @Math101 do you have a PDF or DjVu?

Comment: no, I only have the hardcopy

Comment: Given what you've said (only one week), I would maybe just focus on learning about various types of Cantor sets, such as: **[1]** [Notes 1](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~hart/m424/Cantorset.pdf). **[2]** [Notes 2](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~aaronanderson/CantorSet.pdf). **[3]** [Notes 3](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2013_14/mathcs103_s2014/mathcs103_s2014_zhixing_presentation.pdf). **[4]** [Notes 4](https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/~dnelson/storage/dnelson.cantor-set.pdf). **[5]** The first 18 pages of [Notes 5](http://links.uwaterloo.ca/pmath370docs/week8.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your course's syllabus. For a quick reference you can check this: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf by Terence Tao. Personally I studied by Folland's Real Analysis during my Real Analysis (Measure Theory) course, it's a bit wordy, though clear and good. Hard way: W. Rudin - Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: I have only one week and I am trying to learn measure zero sets only because we are going to need it in Riemann integration.

Comment: Well, if it's just a calculus course, then you don't need any specific knowledge to prepare yourself, you can just directly read the definition of a null set, say from Wikipedia, and you're done. If your course is more about measure theory, then you anyway have to read about all the preceding stuff, i.e. $\sigma$-algebras, measures, measure spaces etc.

Comment: My course is real analysis and within it we are going to learn riemann integrals.

Comment: In this context measure theory course and real analysis are synonyms.

Comment: I mean we do not have anything of measure theory in undergrad course,we just have riemann integral and before starting they have just defined the terms measure zero set and meaning of almost everywhere,do I need more than that?